# How to register new client app in instagram

Tags: validation, sms, instagram

There is a new feature with SMS confirmation. When i trying to register new client, i see SMS validation, enter code from SMS message and receive it:

**Sorry, this page could not be found.**

How can i register new client?

Comment: hi @superyarik, did you get the sms verification? i tried with different mobile phone numbers but never received the sms verification code :(. Btw to register a new client: http://instagram.com/developer/clients/register/

Comment: @LorensiusW.L.T I also am not receiving the SMS verification code. Have tried my mobile and Google Voice, both US numbers to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

After entering the SMS code, try going to the "Manage Client" page again and click on the "Register a new client" button: http://instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/